# how to output coordinate values of feature class to text file

Tags: python, coordinate, arcmap

In the database there is list of feature classes. the codes below can successfully print the x, y of each point of each feature in the feature class. the comment part # is not working, and I dont know how to write the coordinate values of the points to a text file.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = 'database'
fc='file1'
outpath='output Directory' 
cursor=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["OID@","SHAPE@"])
#output=open("result.txt","w")
for row in cursor: #iterate the rows in the table
    print ("Feature {0}: ".format(row[0]))
    for point in row[1].getPart(0):
        print ("{0},{1}".format(point.X, point.Y))  
        #output.write(str(point.X)+""+str(point.Y)+"\n")
        #read_data = output.read()
        #print read_data
#output.close()
```

Any help is appreciated !

the new codes look like:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = 'database'
fc='file1'
outpath='output Directory' 
cursor=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["OID@","SHAPE@"])
with open('result.txt', 'w') as output:
    for row in cursor: #iterate the rows in the table
        for point in row[1].getPart(0):
            output.write(str(point.X)+""+str(point.Y)+"\n")
            print os.path.isfile('result.txt')
output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I checked this with my own python session, and apparently the way to write something to file is .close() it after work. Uncomment your code and write:

```
output.close()
```

...after it. Somehow, even better way to work with files (according to [python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)) is using with statement:

```
>>> with open('workfile', 'r') as output:
...     read_data = output.read()
>>> output.closed
True
```

In your case, write your code below "with open" at indented place. 
Hope it helped.

**Edit:**
This with statement above is just an example from python's documentation.
In your case I suggest trying:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = 'database'
fc='file1'
cursor=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["OID@","SHAPE@"])
with open('result.txt', 'w') as output:
    for row in cursor: #iterate the rows in the table
        print ("Feature {0}: ".format(row[0]))
        for point in row[1].getPart(0):
            print ("{0},{1}".format(point.X, point.Y))  
            output.write(str(point.X)+""+str(point.Y)+"\n")
```

Comment: I added the code output.close() outside the forloop and it didnt raise any error, but no text file was created in the directory either. Is there sth else needed to be fixed? Also i think the With statement you gave doesnt fit in here seems it uses 'r' not 'w'. could you also specify that? tks

Comment: Your result.txt file should be created as soon as you write "output = open('result.txt','w') file, cause AFAIK this is normal python behavior - if file exists, work with it, if not - create it. Check edited answer above, if that doesn't help there must be some other obvious explanation that I don't see at the moment.

Comment: I used your codes and it doesn't create the file either. when i try to print the output using the codes: read_data = output.read()            print read_data  , it just says file not open for reading. So i guess I dont know how to check the output. anyway i am also confused by no files are being created in the output direc

Comment: Once you close() file you cannot read it. If you want to read file after closing it in write mode you must open it with "r" mode for read. Nonetheless, I don't know why python doesn't create files for you - for me it works perfectly.

Comment: see the edits, I am reading it in the forloop after i just write to it. Anyway, the problem is it doesnt create anything. Also it does not give error at all. seems i need to look into more to find out. Tks for help though

Comment: Hmmm. If you add output.read() inside for loop it should raise an error, IOError - file not open for reading (cause you open it with "w" mode, which means - write only). So... it's strange. Okay, let's check something. Write after output = open('result.txt', 'w') this code:

print os.path.isfile('result.txt')

...and "import os" in the top of the document of course (to import this lib). 

There's also another way to create and work with files, using os.open() method. Syntax is little different, but still easy. Anyway, try it:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_open.htm

Comment: Also, are you sure the code you're running have these "#" signs deleted? I know it's dumb question, but I have no idea why these things don't work for you  properly. :)

Comment: Yes I deleted the# . see the edits, I put all the new codes here. I dont know if the 'print' is in right position--in the for loop, but what it gives me is 'True' so I suppose it means it works, but still in the output direc I cannot find the file.

Comment: Or, I could output the attribute table manually by export from the arcmap .. do you know how to do it correctly? save it as dbf or txt doesnt work, all i need is just the attribute shown in excel file.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "output directory", but after running your code result.txt file should appear in the same folder where your python file is. Also, there's no need to close() the output when you're using the with statement. And finally, no, I don't know how to export your data manually from arcmap.

Comment: output directory just let you save file in the different directory than the workspace. I looked in both the workspace and also the output directory(just where the python file is) but the file is not  in any of these. i will ask someone to find out what is the bug.

Comment: Now i have the answer:  full path is needed to created the text file since my workspace is a database, so i use:                 with open('path/folder/result.txt', 'w') as output:                 and now problem solved